# If a random variable $Y$ follows the distribution $F(y)$, is it true that $a + bY$ follows the distribution $F\{(y − a)/b\}$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

(Statistical Models by A. C. Davison, Exercise 2.1.4) If a random variable $Y$ follows the distribution $F(y)$, is it true that $a + bY$ follows the distribution $F\{(y − a)/b\}$?

Why or why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of the distribution function
$$F_Y(y):=\mathbb{P}(Y\leqslant y).$$
Now let $Z:=a+bY$, assuming $b\neq 0$, and $F_Z(z)$ be the distribution function of the random variable $Z$ then again by definition of distribution function we have
$$F_Z(z)=\mathbb{P}(Z\leqslant z)=\mathbb{P}(a+bY\leqslant z)=\mathbb{P}(Y\leqslant \frac{z-a}{b})=F_Y(\frac{z-a}{b}).$$